# Ghost to medium integration

Tags: ghost-blog, mobiledoc-kit

At the end of the article

> https://ghost.org/pt_BR/vs/medium/

there is the sentence:

> You can also publish content to your Ghost site and then syndicate it to Medium as a distribution channel.

Is this a suggestion that this can be automated or should I do it manually? Are there any perspective on ghost v2 (with mobile doc post format) with Medium integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Use **Zapier** to [generate stories in Medium with new Ghost posts](https://zapier.com/apps/ghost/integrations/medium/55608/generate-stories-in-medium-with-new-ghost-posts).

### Full Story

I had the same question. First I searched the Ghost website for "Medium" (using Google).

Sadly, because of the *"Ghost vs. Medium"* link in the footer, I got a gazillion<sup>1</sup> hits. My second attempt, excluding the footer (and then the  "publisher" section and the Forum) [I did not find any specific mention](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aghost.org+%22medium%22-site%3Aforum.ghost.org+-site%3Apublisher.ghost.org+-%22Ghost+vs+Medium%22&oq=site%3Aghost.org+%22medium%22-site%3Aforum.ghost.org+-site%3Apublisher.ghost.org+-%22Ghost+vs+Medium%22).

The same happened when looking for "distribution channel" and "syndication" (and similar terms). Expanding my search to include the [Ghost Github repo](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/) did not change matters any.

Next, looking at the [integrations](https://ghost.org/integrations/), there is also no specific Medium intergration.

There is, however, a [Zapier integration](https://ghost.org/integrations/zapier/). As Zapier offers an integration to [generate stories in Medium with new Ghost posts](https://zapier.com/apps/ghost/integrations/medium/55608/generate-stories-in-medium-with-new-ghost-posts), I'm guessing that is what is being refered to<sup>2</sup>.

It looks like the sales pitch

> You can ... syndicate it to Medium

Really does mean **you** have to syndicate it to Medium yourself. The options you have are to do it manually, use a service like Zapier, or create your own custom automation<sup>3</sup> using either the RSS feed or API.

### Footnotes

1. Feel free to substitue this with your personal favorite [non-numerical vague quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_and_fictitious_numbers)
2. No idea how well things like `rel=canonical` are handled...
3. Apparently thats what the [Stanford Review](https://ghost.org/customers/#stanfordreview) has done as the Ghost "customer" page states:

   > the newspaper has built out its core publication on top of Ghost.